# Show the orders values based on each PERSON from MySQL in PHP when the user logged in

Tags: php, html, mysql

Right now i have a page, where users can Sign Up with their email adres , name and password, when they registered .. they will see a order form. If they place a order .. then i Want to show the product that they ordered in the users profile page.

So right now i have 1 Database , 1 Table and 2 Columns.

Database: Admin_MyWeb

Table : Admin_MyWeb

Column 1: **customers**

Column 2: **orders**

In customers there are are 4 rows: ID, NAME, EMAIl, PASSWORD

In orders there are 3 rows: ID, CUS_NAME, PRODUCT_NAME

Now if someone will register, the details will be stored in **CUSTOMERS**.
When they place a order.. Example: Fruit and press the submit button
The details will be stored in **ORDERS**.

But now i want to show to the ordered details on the user Profile Page Like: Your orders: Fruit

I just want that i can show the ordered product by the user on his page. like something like this:

```
$ echo = PRODUCT_NAME
```

I am using PHP Session login, so when the user will log in he will see this page:

```
    <h1> <?php echo "Hi ".$_SESSION['user_name']; ?> <i class="fa fa-user"></i></h1>
            <h3><?php echo "".$_SESSION['user_email']; ?></h3>
            <hr>
            No orders yet <br>

            <a href="order" > Click here to order</a>
```

But IF he will place a order, i want to show the order (product_name) after he will place that order!

```
<h1> <?php echo "Hi ".$_SESSION['user_name']; ?> <i class="fa fa-user"></i></h1>
                <h3><?php echo "".$_SESSION['user_email']; ?></h3>
                <hr>
                You have ordered 1 product:
                - Fruit  <br>

                <a href="order" > Click here to order more</a>
```

Comment: So what's your question, or are you asking how to code an entire eCommerce platform in PHP?

Comment: NO!, Read again please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try save users orders in other table, that you did in orders, and make an inner join for retrieving all products your users have ordered.

like :
select * from users where user = "$_SESSION[USER]"

just notice about injections.

for your example:

```
 <h1> <?php echo "Hi ".$_SESSION['user_name']; ?> <i class="fa fa-user"></i></h1>
            <h3><?php echo "".$_SESSION['user_email']; ?></h3>
            <hr>
            $query = "SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE USER = $_SESSION[user_name]; "

 // excute your query with your methods and I assume the $array is result
 echo "My great turkish user: " . count($array) . " orders ! <br />";
 foreach ($array as $record) {
 echo "$record[product_name] <br />";

 }

            <a href="order" > Click here to order more</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i already created a another table for the orders, but still i  can not show the users orders on users session page?

Comment: I have added some solution to answer, if not enough, how do you work with db?

Comment: Thanks men! But there is some error, check this : http://i.imgur.com/QIB4yWb.png

Comment: can you help me with TeamViewer please?

Comment: never used TeamViewer ever, I wished but not possible. Tell me how do you connect to database and run your queries?

Comment: I have forgetting add ; into ` $query = "SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE USER = $_SESSION[user_name]; "`

Comment: Yes, check this : http://justpaste.it/forali

Comment: http://justpaste.it/lige

Comment: This is the Database: http://i.imgur.com/s1EjhgZ.png

Comment: Just look to the link I've sent you, it includes simple solution of retriving data from database, you need to use mysql_fetch_assoc for prinitng users orders.

Comment: Thanks but i think there is something wrong with the structure of my db? can you send me the .sql file plsz?

Comment: are you using same name columns in file? there is not any problem with your db, what's the error?

Comment: This is working, http://justpaste.it/Newali .. But what if a user  have more orders? I mean, i need to extract the row : product_order for that user.. So if he will submit that form again, the other product will show + on that

Comment: It's about how to optimize your form, simply you can a random number to form and set it in session and compare them when you want added to database.

Comment: Can i talk with you on my chat platform please? i have some questions... I am online: http://design-studios.nl/chat just type only your name and hit enter! thanks